# Detect connected bluetooth devices to iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, wcsession

I am trying to know if iPhone has paired and connected Apple Watch and get identifier of Apple Watch.
WCSession only provides ability to check if iPhone has paired Watch.
I need to know if Apple Watch connected in settings not by this application I am trying to write.
thanks :)